# ClearCase: Are views created in Unix not visible from Windows and vice versa?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We have a ClearCase UCM project implementation that we access from Windows and Solaris stations.
I have created several views on the same stream of the project from the CC project explorer in both Windows and Solaris.

But when I go into the properties of the stream and look for views from CC project explorer in Windows, I don't see the views I created from Solaris and vice versa.
But from CC project explorer in Windows, I can see views created from other Windows stations.

Whats happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is the notion of **regions**: you would usually define one region per Os, precisely to not see (and list with a cleartool lsview) *all* the views.

- The windows ones will have a global path with a windows-like schema: `\\server\share\path\to\view_storage`.
- The Unix ones will have a global path with a Unix mount: `/mount/server/path/to/view_storage`

Both paths wouldn't be usable by the opposite Os, so there is no point seeing all the views: you need only the ones for your Os.

---

See "[registry regions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/rgy-admin.htm)" and `cleartool lsreg`  for more on those regions.
They apply also for Vobs (not just views):

[image: ClearCase regions for Vobs and Views]