# Using Clearcase and Eclipse for C++

Tags: c, eclipse, clearcase

I work on a large C/C++ project and the code base is maintained in Clearcase. Till date we primarily work in Linux environment and we don't extensively use IDE. We directly checkout and edit files through VI.

Since I got access to Clearcase for Windows access, I am now trying to access the sources files in Eclipse. I primarily want to use Eclipse for Editing and Code Navigation. I create views through my unix account. I am able to mount the same view on my Windows PC using Clearcase Explorer. I am able to access the code and make changes to the file that were checked out earlier.

Can someone familiar to Eclipse please let me know how I can view that code base in eclipse. I do NOT want to create copies of the code base in my local filesystem. If I try creating a new project with the code base drive as the root folder, the project wont get created since I don't have write permission in that folder.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Do you have a ClearCase view on your Linux machine, and you want to work on it with Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can mount your Linux filesystem on windows, you should be able to reference the sources directly from Eclipse.

The most important detail, for the ClearCase plugin to work is for the `.project` to and `.classpath` files to be right alongside the sources, in your snapshot view.
See:

- "[When committing projects should I include `.project` & `.classpath`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9808263/6309)"
- "[imported Eclipse project not linking to ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432945/imported-eclipse-project-not-linking-to-clearcase/4433604#4433604)"
- "[Clearcase plugin for eclipse usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857)"

For that Unix view to be recognize from Windows, you would have to tag and register it in the Windows region: "[ClearCase: Are views created in Unix not visible from Windows and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572145/clearcase-are-views-created-in-unix-not-visible-from-windows-and-vice-versa/7573651#7573651)".

Note that the case of snapshot views (accessing Unix views from windows), as this [help page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/before_access_different_ssv.htm) details, any ClearCase operation might *fail*:
See "[Before accessing snapshot views across different platforms](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/before_access_different_ssv.htm)"

> You can access snapshot views across different platforms, but you cannot issue Rational ClearCase commands across platforms.
>   For example, **you cannot check out files in snapshot views on UNIX workstations from Rational ClearCase hosts on Windows computers**, nor can you create shortcuts to snapshot views on UNIX workstations from Rational ClearCase Explorer.
>
> If you are on a Rational ClearCase host running on a Windows computer and you hijack a file in a UNIX snapshot view, the hijack is detected when you update the view from a Rational ClearCase host on a UNIX platform.

In your case, if by "mounting" you mean mount dynamic view, then you should be ok, as mentioned in this [help page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_mvfs/c_about_access_ux_dyn_from_win.htm), use Region Synchronizer to import the Linux or UNIX view tag of the view into your Windows network region.

Comment: It seems like he uses dynamic views (he mounts them using ClearCase Explorer), so your warning about snapshot views are irrelevant.

Comment: @ugoren true, I have edited my answer to add a section addressing dynamic views.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed instructions. 

I have used the Region Synchronizer and I am able to access my dynamic views in Windows. 

No other team member is using Eclipse so I will not be able to make .project and .classpath (its a C/C++ project not sure if .classpath is required) as clearcase elements. Is there a way to work around this problem. I am ok if I am not able to checkout files within Eclipse (though this would be really helpful). Is it possible to add the source folders to an Eclipse project as if they are uncontrolled files? I should be able to build the indexes?

Comment: @Ashwin you can reference sources in your CDT project, wherever they are (and whether or not they are versioned). See a tutorial like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt1KW2ZULV8 (after http://stackoverflow.com/q/8013481/6309)